# Amine JS make a element in center

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, anime.js

I am trying to make a portfolio.
My intro has a dom like this

```html
        <div className={clsx("inline-flex", "items-center",
          "space-x-4")}>
          <div id="logo" className={"flex"}>
            <LoaderIcon isOnLoader={true}/>
          </div>
          <div className={"flex flex-col"} id={"title_container"}>
            <div id="subtitle" className={"text-neon-violet"}>
              {descriptionSmall}
            </div>
            <div id={"title"} className={"text-neon-violet text-4xl tracking-tighter"}>
              {title}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

In the animation, I am shrinking the `#title_container` to 0 using

```js
loader.add({
        targets: "#title_container",
        duration: 800,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
        scale: 0,
      })
```

The `#title_container` is going out, but the `#logo` stays in the same place.

I want to make the animation like the title is shrinking and the logo is coming center at the same time.

Please help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know we have a timeline in animejs. We keep on adding the elements which need to be animated.

Here's link to timeline docs for animejs.
https://animejs.com/documentation/#timelineBasics

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).